# How to redirect from an area page to root page in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redirect, razor-pages

How do I redirect from an area page to the root directory page in .NET 5 Razor Pages.?

Below screenshot is what exactly I am trying to achieve.

[image]

Here is my **Login.cshtml.cs** page looks like:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;

        public LoginModel(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, 
            ILogger<LoginModel> logger,
            UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        [TempData]
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
           // [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            public string Email { get; set; }

          //  [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
            public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
        }

        public void OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
            }

            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        }

        public IActionResult OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Home"); // This is not working          
        }
    }
}
```

Not understanding where I am going wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that the Home page is outside of any areas? From the image it looks like is under the Areas subfolder

Comment: Yes, the home page is outside the area folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `RedirectToPage("/Home")` instead of `RedirectToAction("/Home")`